# How does one retrieve and collect the index of an array item's first occurrence also taking a consecutive order of same items into account?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reduce

I am counting the Consecutive Zeros and treating each one as separate block and pushing it to array blocks like this [3,1,1] , **what i need to do is to push the position of first element in each block in another array like this [2,13,15]**

```
var A = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0];
var N = A.length
function Avaiblocks(A,N,X){
  var counter = 0;
  var Blocks = [];
  var POS =[];
    
  for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if(A[i] === 0){
          counter++;
          POS.push(i) 
        } else {
            if (counter !== 0) {
                Blocks.push(counter)
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter !== 0){
      Blocks.push(counter)
        }
return POS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

let result = Array.from(arr.join("").matchAll(/0+/g),m=>m['index'])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the given array with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce_works).

Pass the reducer function and an additional empty array as collector to it.

For each iteration the reduce function has access to its collector (here `list`), the currently processed `item`, the current `idx`(index) and the processed `arr`(array) itself.

The next iteration treats the return value of the former/current iteration as collector/`list` again.

Thus, for the OP's example, one needs to return an array which, for each iteration, either concats the current `idx` in case the first `0` value of a sequence of consecutive zeros was found (hence the condition ... `(item === 0 && arr[idx - 1] !== 0)`) or does concat an empty array and returns this result ...

```js
function collectIndexOfFirstOneOfConsecutiveZeros(list, item, idx, arr) {
  return list.concat(
    (item === 0 && arr[idx - 1] !== 0)
    ? idx
    : []
  );
}
const sampleList = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0];

console.log(
  sampleList.reduce(collectIndexOfFirstOneOfConsecutiveZeros, [])
);

// ... or directly like ...

console.log(
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    .reduce((list, item, idx, arr) =>
      list.concat((item === 0 && arr[idx - 1] !== 0) ? idx : []),
      []
    )
);
```

Comment: @Sue ... out of curiosity ... how come the flag was removed from an already accepted answer ... or ... what was not explained well enough to you in order to you having gotten a better understanding of how the problem gets solved best from the now accepted answer?